# Wordpress - jQuery follow button to select the user id

Tags: jquery, wordpress, button

I have this jQuery to follow/unfollow users by using plugin "[Users Following System](https://pippinsplugins.com/series/creating-a-user-follow-system-plugin/)", I am showing a list of users using get_users with foreach loop.

If i added the follow button shortcode inside the foreach loop..

The problem I am facing is when i click on the follow button for one user, the loading images for all users show up and all the follow links get toggled `$(‘.follow-links a’).toggle();`

So how can i target to select the only user i clicked! Thanks in advance.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    /*******************************
    follow / unfollow a user
    *******************************/
    $( '.follow-links a' ).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this);

        if( pwuf_vars.logged_in != 'undefined' && pwuf_vars.logged_in != 'true' ) {
            alert( pwuf_vars.login_required );
            return;
        }

        var data      = {
            action:    $this.hasClass('follow') ? 'follow' : 'unfollow',
            user_id:   $this.data('user-id'),
            follow_id: $this.data('follow-id'),
            nonce:     pwuf_vars.nonce
        };

        $('img.pwuf-ajax').show();

        $.post( pwuf_vars.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            if( response == 'success' ) {
                $('.follow-links a').toggle();
            } else {
                alert( pwuf_vars.processing_error );
            }
            $('img.pwuf-ajax').hide();
        } );
    });
});
```

this is the HTML markup for the follow link button.

```
<?php
/**
 * Retrieves the follow / unfollow links
 *
 * @access      public
 * @since       1.0
 * @param       int $user_id - the ID of the user to display follow / unfollow links for
 * @return      string
 */

function pwuf_get_follow_unfollow_links( $follow_id = null ) {

    global $user_ID;

    if( empty( $follow_id ) )
        return;

    if( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    if ( $follow_id == $user_ID )
        return;

    ob_start(); ?>
    <div class="follow-links">
        <?php if ( pwuf_is_following( $user_ID, $follow_id ) ) { ?>
            <span><a href="#" class="unfollow followed" data-user-id="<?php echo $user_ID; ?>" data-follow-id="<?php echo $follow_id; ?>"><span>Following</a></span>
            <a href="#" class="follow" style="display:none;" data-user-id="<?php echo $user_ID; ?>" data-follow-id="<?php echo $follow_id; ?>">Follow</a>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <a href="#" class="follow" data-user-id="<?php echo $user_ID; ?>" data-follow-id="<?php echo $follow_id; ?>">Follow</a>
            <span><a href="#" class="followed unfollow" style="display:none;" data-user-id="<?php echo $user_ID; ?>" data-follow-id="<?php echo $follow_id; ?>"><span>Following</a></span>
        <?php } ?>
        <img src="<?php echo PWUF_FOLLOW_URL; ?>/images/loading.gif" class="pwuf-ajax" style="display:none;"/>
    </div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the HTML it's difficult to say. However, `$('img.pwuf-ajax').show();` will indeed show all images with a class of `pwuf-ajax` and `$('.follow-links a').toggle();` will likewise toggle all `a` elements contained within a parent of class `follow-links`. So, you will probably need to target your selectors to children of `$this` using [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: `$('.follow-links a').toggle();`  replace with  `$this.toggle();`

Comment: Thanks @PeterHvD for your reply, Please check now i updated my question.

Comment: Thanks @Shahin, I tried it but the same problem is there.

Comment: The problem is that you have 2 `a` elements in the DOM which are actually the same, except for their classes. So, although in theory `$this.toggle();` is a better selector, it doesn't help the rest of your js to know what you're clicking on. I'd suggest simplifying your HTML so that there is only the one `a` element and changing the classes when clicked. After that you will then need to target just the `img.pwuf-ajax` that is immediately after the `a` so as to not fire all of them on the rest of the page, using something like `$this.next('img.pwuf-ajax').show();`

Comment: Thanks @PeterHvD for your explanation, but please can you give me a real answer of that, because i'm a little bit lost. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I do believe that the best way to learn is to be nudged in the right direction to solve it for yourself, but here's how I would change your code:

*NOTE: I have tested the jQuery and it does work, but this is all in theory as I don't have the plugin that you're using so can't test it fully.*

First, change the contents of `<div class="follow-links">` to:

```
<?php
if ( pwuf_is_following( $user_ID, $follow_id ) ) {
    $classes = "unfollow";
    $text = "Following";
} else {
    $classes = "follow";
    $text = "Follow";
}
?>
<span><a href="#" class="<?php echo $classes; ?>" data-user-id="<?php echo $user_ID; ?>" data-follow-id="<?php echo $follow_id; ?>"><span><?php echo $text; ?></span></a></span>
<img src="<?php echo PWUF_FOLLOW_URL; ?>/images/loading.gif" class="pwuf-ajax" style="display:none;"/>
```

You can see that we're only outputting one `a` element, and adding the appropriate class and text. I've wrapped the text in a `span` so that we can change it with jQuery. BTW, you have 2 classes "unfollow followed" in your code, but you're not setting the "followed" one programatically. I don't know it that's an issue?

Second, change the JS to this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
    /*******************************
    follow / unfollow a user
    *******************************/
    $( '.follow-links a' ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $( this );

        if ( pwuf_vars.logged_in != 'undefined' && pwuf_vars.logged_in != 'true' ) {
            alert( pwuf_vars.login_required );
            return;
        }

        var data = {
            action: $this.hasClass( 'follow' ) ? 'follow' : 'unfollow',
            user_id: $this.data( 'user-id' ),
            follow_id: $this.data( 'follow-id' ),
            nonce: pwuf_vars.nonce
        };

        $this.next( 'img.pwuf-ajax' ).show();

        $.post( pwuf_vars.ajaxurl, data, function ( response ) {
            if ( response == 'success' ) {
                if ( $this.hasClass( 'follow' ) ) {;
                    $this.removeClass( 'follow' ).addClass( 'unfollow' );
                    $this.find( 'span' ).text( 'Unfollow' );
                } else {;
                    $this.removeClass( 'unfollow' ).addClass( 'follow' );
                    $this.find( 'span' ).text( 'Follow' );
                }
            } else {
                alert( pwuf_vars.processing_error );
            }
            $this.next( 'img.pwuf-ajax' ).hide();
        } );
    } );
} );
```

You could use `.toggleClass()` to toggle the classes, but because we also want to change the text in the `span` I've chosen to do the work of `.toggleClass()` manually. So, yes, there is a shorter way of doing this using `.toggleClass() with a callback function, but I think that this is easier for you to follow what is happening.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello Dear @PeterHvD, I used your answer from along time and it's working perfectly, but i have another small issue, could you please help me to fix it, Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54840542/wordpress-follow-user-button-not-working-when-added-inside-ajax-pagination-temp